# I want to enroll myself in college

Tags: grammar

> I want to enroll in college.
>
> I want to enroll myself in college.

Enroll or enroll myself if I want to study at a college when I talk to the receptionist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the verb *enroll* is a transitive and intrasitive verb, you can say either "to enroll in college" or "to enroll myself in college".

Both are grammatical, but it's far more common and idiomatic to drop the reflexive pronoun (as myself) after the verb enroll unless you emphasize the pronoun (subject). So you say:

> I want to enroll in college.

Answer (score 1):

Both usages are correct, the verb "**enroll**" is both transitive and intransitive:

- *intransitive* - To enlist oneself (in something) or become a member (of something).
- *transitive* - To enlist (someone) or make (someone) a member of.

Note that the verb can be spelled "**enrol**" as well in British spelling. Actually, the double l is called "*irregular inflection*" but is popular is American spelling.

As for the prepositions you can use for/in/on/at/with or even without a preposition. Take a look here [**Cambridge Dictionary**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/enrol?a=british) or here [**MacMillan Dictionary**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/enrol)